# Lookup and display from all Sheets

Tags: excel

Not sure if this is possible but here it goes:

I have a suppliers spreadsheet, I constantly add supplied products we use for the supplier, each supplier has its own sheet and I constantly add more so there is no set amount of sheets. Most products have a category. what I would like is a dropdown list on the first sheet where you select for example 'card' then it will show the full row where ever, in any sheet, the category paper is found.

I need the row to load as it will contain stuff like price, width etc etc.

I have attached a basic layout of what I have, as you can see on the sheet 'Category Lookup', this is where I want to select card for example, and then any information will display on that page.

Is this possible? I hope i explained it well enough.

[My Sample Excel File](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/avf6iyhqef7wxt1o3hkrk/Work-in-Progress-Supplier-Costs-Sheet.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=yoys2nv5oo8urjhatoa79pcqv)

Comment: Voting to close as `needs focus` due to current post will lead to subjective answers, where the SO forum intent is to provide an objective answer to a specific issue.  That said, there are so many possible ways to do this:  copying lines from each sheet into an assessment sheet; creating an array that gets displayed in a userform; allowing for a more narrowed search within a userform that starts with the card and slowly narrows... the list goes on and on.  find a style that suits you and then re-work your question to a more narrow scope.

Comment: @cyril the question was if it is possible. Nothing wrong with it. He doesn't know the possibilities and therefore can't ask more specific.

Comment: @Prema "is it possible" is answered with a "yes" and then you move on; that doesn't add value to the repository of questions/answers.  It's a toss up on if this is closed for `asking for resources`, `needs focus`, etc.  I am not saying it's a bad thing to ask, but I am saying it needs to be more focused to be a useful question for people reviewing in the future who have similar inquiry.  This ties back to the post [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, I will not build the whole solution for you because it takes time.

Build a formula with concatenate parts of the formula including the sheet names (a list of sheet names in a column where you manually add the name of a sheet when you add a new supplier)

Formula could be in this style:

```
=VSTACK(FILTER('Supplier 1'!A6:N7;'Supplier 1'!G6:G7=B1);FILTER('Supplier 2'!A6:N9;'Supplier 2'!G6:G9=B1))
```

For Example the build formula string is in A1

Then create a new name e.g. "MyData"
With the formula =Evaluate(&A&1)

Then go to the cell where you want the data and write
=MyData

The only thing then, you need to add a sheet name to the list, so your formula string is updated.

Maybe helpful links:

https://superuser.com/questions/253353/excel-function-that-evaluates-a-string-as-if-it-were-a-formula

https://www.xelplus.com/lookup-values-across-multiple-worksheets-excel/

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was trying to figure out your formula but released VSTACK is only available in Office 365 and i have Excel 2021 so trying to find an alternative for VSTACK

Comment: It is also possible with other more complicated formulas. You can Google that. If you don't want to use complicated formulas, use power query to combine sheets, on that combined sheet use filter function.. Very simple, worth learning it. Check YouTube